# How do I log into Windows 7 as an Administrator

Tags: windows-7

How do I log into Windows 7 as an Administrator. The key combination in XP was <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> x 2.

What is the key combination for Windows 7?

Answer (score 3):

Refer **[Windows 7 - Built-in Administrator Account - Enable or Disable](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/507-built-administrator-account-enable-disable.html)** for more info.

Look at the OPTION ONE on this site.

> ### Through Local Users and Groups
>
> **NOTE:**    This option will only be available in the Windows 7 Professional, Ultimate, and Enterprise editions.
>
> 1. Open the **Local Users and Groups** manager.
> 2. In the left pane, click on the Users folder.
> 3. In the middle pane, right click on **Administrator** and click on **Properties**.
> 4. To Enable the Buit-in Administrator Account
>      A) Uncheck the **Account is disabled** box.
>      B) Go to step 6.
> 5. To Disable the Buit-in Administrator Account
>      A) Check the **Account is disabled** box.
> 6. Click on OK.
> 7. Close the Local Users and Groups window.
> 8. Log off, and you will now see the built-in Administrator account log on icon added (enabled) or removed (disabled) from the log on
>      screen.
>
> **NOTE:** Click on the **Administrator** icon to log on to the built-in Administrator account.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the start menu and type `cmd` in search box and then right click on it and run it with option `Run as Admin`. Now type the exact command
`C:\>net user administrator /active:yes`.
 Now restart the system and you will see that your `Admin` account is enable.

Answer (score -1):

Keep in mind, unless you disabled User Access Control you will still need to answer prompts to elevate your privilege when you want to actually act as an administrator.

Comment: This is untrue.  For a non-domain joined install, the admin approval mode for the Admin account is turned **on**.

Comment: I think that is what I said.  Are you saying that it cannot be turned off?

Comment: Admin Approval mode features UAC being enabled, but you won't get any prompts. Depending on the settings, this can be applied to all Admin accounts, not just the built in one.

Comment: UAC is customizable through registry values, which are set by the local security policy.