# Delete cygwin folder altogether?

Tags: windows-7, permissions

I had cygwin installed in my last version of Windows. Reinstalled it, without first removing cygwin. The new installation kept all my old files. After the re installation, I chose to delete the old files but I can't find a way to remove cygwin. It keeps telling me that I don't have the permission to remove it.
Tried to delete it from Linux, Ubuntu from a Live USB, but it moved it into a Thrash folder and still can't delete it when I log into Windows again. Booted into Safe Mode, but can't find a way to change to the Administrator user (maybe there isn't one anymore on Windows 7? an administrator user by default, besides the first user created during installation).
I tried to change the permission from Properties -> Security but I get an Access denied error. Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure about the permissions problem, but you can [enable the built-in administrator account](http://superuser.com/questions/385534/how-do-i-log-into-windows-7-as-an-administrator). Note that this may not help you with the permissions, and may open a security hole - it's disabled for a reason, since the built-in administrator account does not have UAC enabled.

Comment: @Bob doesn't work. I still get "Access denied". Even tried to run cmd as Administrator, still the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I delete the cygwin folder on my c drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/485297/how-can-i-delete-the-cygwin-folder-on-my-c-drive)

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem. I googled for an answer and arrived here, but none worked for me.

#### What I did:

I had to grant all accounts full access from the Security tab. Then I deleted the folder.
Although it wasn't that easy. First, you will have to go into Advanced security settings to make yourself the "Owner" of the folder from owner tab (Check the box below too).
After applying, I could grant myself access easily, and delete the folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you feel familiar with a *nix environment (of course, you used cygwin), try the Live CD/USB again. But this time, use the console `rm -rf` command. Be **very** careful that you are actually deleting the correct folder, since that command can quite easily destroy your whole system.

I don't have a *nix environment to test in at the moment, but there was a flag (`I`, I think) that makes `r` (recursive) removal much safer with a confirmation prompt. You should probably use `rm -rfI` for this added safety.